# Use data.table to calculate the percentage of occurrence depending on the category in another column

Tags: r, data.table

Recently I'm working with data.table in R and it is quite popular and efficient. Currently I come across a problem which I think could be solved using data.table.

I have a data set like this:

```
event | group_ind 
  1   | group1
  1   | group1
  1   | group1
  2   | group1
  2   | group1
  1   | group2
  1   | group2
  2   | group2
  2   | group3
  2   | group3
```

Now I want to know the percentage of event 1 occurs in each group. The result for this data set is obvious: 60% for event 1 in group1, 67% in group2 and 0 in group3. In reality the data set has many more observations with more than 2 event types and rows are not sorted in a certain order. I can get what I want in a very dummy way in R (by counting occurrence in event column divided by total observations in each group) but I think there should be a fancier way of doing this.

So the result I want would be like this:

```
 event | group_ind | percentage
   1   | group1    | 0.6
   2   | group1    | 0.4
   1   | group2    | 0.67
   2   | group2    | 0.33
   1   | group3    | 0
   2   | group3    | 100
```

I hope this can be done in data.table. Much appreciate for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple solution would be just

```
setDT(DT)[, .(event = 1:2, percentage = tabulate(event)/.N), by = group_ind]
#    group_ind event percentage
# 1:    group1     1  0.6000000
# 2:    group1     2  0.4000000
# 3:    group2     1  0.6666667
# 4:    group2     2  0.3333333
# 5:    group3     1  0.0000000
# 6:    group3     2  1.0000000
```

Though a more general solution would be to use `unique` on `event` (and also pre-order it - as suggested by @EdM).

```
setDT(DT)[order(event), .(event = unique(event), percentage = tabulate(event)/.N), by = group_ind]
```

Comment: From my understanding, this solution works if all groups have at least one occurrence of each event. I'm looking for a more general method that allows for instance, no occurrence of event 1 for group 1 in the initial data.frame and still have the event column in the output that is correct. Any idea?

Comment: @EdM This solution works even if one of the events is missing in a certain group(s), did you even try it prior speculating? This is *exactly* why added the more general solution solution too.

Comment: @ David Arenburg, I'm deeply sorry, but my comment was made too fast, indeed. I've tried the general solution using a data.table I have and as the results were not correct, I've just assumed it was because of the missing events. Actually, the problem comes from the `unique` that goes through the `by`. In my case, I have some groups where event 2 appears before event 1. I've solved my problem with `setDT(DT)[ order(event), .(event = unique(event), percentage = tabulate(event)/.N), by = group_ind]`. Isn't it an even more general solution to be proposed?