# Calculating the percent occurrence of multiple table columns in r

Tags: r, data.table

I have a table that looks as follows - A number of businesses, a number of practices (P1 - P4) that they might engage in, and a column called 'Peer' which is a grouping column (yes - peer, no - no peer). All practice columns are yes/no:

```
Business    P1  P2  P3  P4  Peer
a   y   n   y   n   y
b   n   n   y   n   n
c   n   y   y   n   y
d   y   y   y   y   n
e   n   n   n   y   y
f   n   n   n   y   n
g   y   y   n   n   y
h   n   y   n   n   n
i   n   n   y   n   y
j   y   n   y   y   n
k   n   y   y   y   n
l   n   y   y   y   n
m   y   n   n   n   n
n   n   n   n   n   y
o   n   y   n   n   y
p   y   y   n   y   n
q   n   n   y   y   y
r   n   n   y   y   n
s   y   y   y   n   y
t   n   y   y   n   y
u   n   n   n   n   y
v   y   n   n   y   n
w   n   y   n   y   n
x   n   y   n   y   y
y   y   n   y   n   n
z   n   n   y   n   y
```

What I want to achieve from this is a summary table that shows the following, where `percentage` is the number of businesses which have taken up the practice (practice == "y"):

```
Peer    Practice    percentage
y   P1  30
y   P2  40
y   P3  33
y   P4  90
n   P1  20
n   P2  30
n   P3  11
n   P4  75
```

Note I have not calculated the percentages in the second table, they are made up.

While I think this should be achievable with data.table ([this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33946334/use-data-table-to-calculate-the-percentage-of-occurrence-depending-on-the-catego) is particularly relevant) I can only work out what seems to me an over-elaborate way to create this table. Example for P1:

Firstly, calculate the percentage occurrences in each category for this practice:

```
P1Stats <- setDT(dtUptake)[order(Peer), .(P1 = unique(P1), percentage = 100 * tabulate(P1)/.N), by = Peer]

   Peer P1 percentage
1:    n  n   53.84615
2:    n  y   46.15385
3:    y  y   76.92308
4:    y  n   23.07692
```

From the results, only select the rows where the uptake of `P1` is "y":

```
P1Stats <- P1Stats[P1=="y"]


   Peer P1 percentage
1:    n  y   46.15385
2:    y  y   76.92308
```

Change the name of the column `P1` to `Practice`

```
P1Stats <- P1Stats[, .(Peer, Practice = P1, percentage)]

   Peer Practice percentage
1:    n        y   46.15385
2:    y        y   76.92308
```

Replace the `y` value in the `Practice` column with the practice name `P1`:

```
P1Stats[, Practice := "P1"]

   Peer Practice percentage
1:    n       P1   46.15385
2:    y       P1   76.92308
```

Then, if I carry this out for each of my practices I can create the final table by pulling them all together. I understand that I can amalgamate the three top steps into one, and then do the update process after that:

`P1Stats <-  setDT(dtUptake)[order(Peer), .(P1 = unique(P1), percentage = 100 * tabulate(P1)/.N), by = Peer][P1=="y"][, .(Peer, Practice = P1, percentage)]`

`P1Stats[, Practice := "P1"]`

However, this is still not very elegant. I would like to know if there is a way to make this process more streamlined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `melt` and `data.table`'s `by` parameter, you can achieve that. For instance, supposing your original `data.table` is in variable `dt` here:

```
dt2 = melt.data.table(dt, id.vars=c('Business', 'Peer'), variable.name='practice')
dt2[,.(percentage=sum(value=='y')/.N*100), by=c('Peer','practice')]
```

The `by` operation will group on values of a column, or set of columns. As the original data has those values that are intended for grouping (P1,P2,P3,P4) not in column values, but spread in different column names, the long format produced by `melt` is the way to go.

Comment: Thank you. The melt operation works perfectly, but the second part where the percentage is calculated returns an error: `Error in list(percentage = sum(value == "y")/.N) * 100 : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator`.

Comment: Thank you both - this is now working fine. Struggling a little after 20 years of Excel and Access, R is quite a learning curve. But a fun one.